# how to serve a content over https

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am facing problem when I call an api end point url from a https page. I have hosted my front-end code in aws s3 bucket and a third party ssl certificate is deployed .so my react code is served over https. And my back-end is deployed inside a single instance application of elastic bean stalk. while I am trying to call my back-end url from my front-end application, it is throwing the below error.

Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your ELB (AWS Elastic Beanstalk) application to use SSL/HTTPS

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

You can set this up with Route53 and AWS Certificate Manager (ACM).

Comment: once this is done, you need to change your html and define the https link.